# What should I do if I forgot to dry fries before baking?

Tags: baking, potatoes, french-fries

What should I do if I forgot to dry off my fries before putting them in to bake?

And now they're seasoned and oiled up.

Comment: I appreciate that this question was asked in a hurry – if you have a chance to tidy it up and add some detail (what type of fries you are making, what your method was, etc) then it might be more useful for future readers.

Answer (score 10):

Bake them anyway and accept that they might not be quite as good as they would otherwise be. A little extra moisture won't be fatal, and there's nothing you can easily do now. You could try patting them with a paper towel but it's likely to remove the seasoning more than it removes water.

Comment: Baking at a slightly higher temperature for a few minutes at first would also help evaporate off the water, which might let them crisp up more, like they normally would.

Comment: How about opening the oven door very briefly periodically to let out excess steam?

Comment: @Jessa If you found my answer helpful, you can use the button under the voting arrows to mark it as accepted. I hope your fries came out well! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can still attempt to dry them with a hair dryer. This may sound weird to some people, but it's a thing, and I've done this once or twice when I'm having trouble drying foods.

[image]
<sub>[Source](https://www.theartofdoingstuff.com/how-to-make-perfect-french-fries/)</sub>

To avoid oil or seasoning from flying off of your fries, I recommend using the lowest setting on your hairdryer, or keep it a fair distance away from the fries when drying them.

Comment: if they're already oiled I imagine water will have a hard time evaporating off until the oil's already blown away